# Wso2 Jax-RS Service project cant load Wso2 dependencies

Tags: java, web-services, maven, wso2, osgi

I am developing a Jax-RS Service project using the Wso2 Development Studio.
I want to use some classes of other Wso2 modules. So i try to include those in the project as maven dependencies.

However it seems that i am doing something wrong because i can not make the dependencies to work.

For example i am having these dependencies

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.user.core</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.core</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.core.common</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

But when i try to use something out of those packages i get a class not found

```
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException;


@Path("/")
public class Users {

    @GET
    public String getUsers()
    {
        return "this is v0.0.1";
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public String createUser() throws UserStoreException
    {
        throw new UserStoreException("this is an erro message but it worked");
        return "creatd";
    }
}
```

In this example the `UserStoreException` can't even be imported.

This is how i import the packages needed

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <obrRepository>NONE</obrRepository>
          <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-Name>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
            <Bundle-Version>0.0.1</Bundle-Version>
                        <Export-Package>
                            example.*
                        </Export-Package>
            <Import-Package>
                  org.wso2.carbon.*,
                  org.apache.commons.logging.*,
                  org.osgi.framework.*,
                  javax.naming.*,
                  org.osgi.service.component.*
           </Import-Package>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

do i have something wrong in the import ?

What should i do to import Wso2 dependencies successfully?

Here is the full exception stack trace on the server:

```
type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet cxf threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

    javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet cxf threw exception
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:72)
        org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
        org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
        org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
        org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    root cause

    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'UsersBean' defined in URL [jndi:/localhost/wso2usersapi-0.0.1/WEB-INF/cxf-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/user/core/UserStoreException
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:526)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.createSpringContext(CXFServlet.java:151)
        org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.loadBus(CXFServlet.java:74)
        org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.init(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:76)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:72)
        org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
        org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
        org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
        org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    root cause

    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/user/core/UserStoreException
        java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
        org.apache.cxf.common.util.ReflectionUtil$6.run(ReflectionUtil.java:127)
        org.apache.cxf.common.util.ReflectionUtil$6.run(ReflectionUtil.java:125)
        java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        org.apache.cxf.common.util.ReflectionUtil.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtil.java:125)
        org.apache.cxf.common.annotation.AnnotationProcessor.processMethods(AnnotationProcessor.java:85)
        org.apache.cxf.common.annotation.AnnotationProcessor.accept(AnnotationProcessor.java:72)
        org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:118)
        org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:112)
        org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(Jsr250BeanPostProcessor.java:136)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:393)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1415)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.createSpringContext(CXFServlet.java:151)
        org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.loadBus(CXFServlet.java:74)
        org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.init(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:76)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:72)
        org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
        org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
        org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
        org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since wso2 artifacts are not synched with the maven central you may get errors when trying to build the project.
Could you please add the following repositories to your pom.xml and do the build.

```
<repositories>
        <!-- WSO2 released artifact repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>wso2.releases</id>
            <name>WSO2 Releases Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>

        <!-- WSO2 Snapshot artifact repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>wso2.snapshots</id>
            <name>WSO2 Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>wso2-nexus</id>
            <name>WSO2 internal Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Comment: I did add those but locally i run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and it downloaded many jars. However i am deploying the carbon application to the server and it still says that it does not find the `UserStoreException`. Do i have to do something specific when building the application ?

Comment: Have you properly mentioned all import packages in import-package section?

Comment: I update the question showing the `Import-package`. Does it seem to be correct?

Comment: Attached the full stack trace from the server, hope it gives you an insight. Thank you.

Comment: What is the product and version that you put this jar file?

Comment: Its the Identity Server v5.3.0

Comment: Your dependency versions should be 4.4.11. BUt that shouldn;t be an issue. Can you check whether org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.4.11.jar available in plugins directory

Comment: Yes it exists in `wso2is-5.3.0/repository/components/plugins/org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.4.11.jar`.
I should change my dependency on `4.4.11`, right ?

Comment: `org.wso2.carbon.u‌​ser.core`  `4.4.11` does not exist in the maven repository though. It goes up to 4.2.0 . Am i searching on the right place https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wso2.carbon/org.wso2.carbon.core?

Comment: It is not synced with maven central. Did you add the repos I mentioned earliuer

Comment: Yeah i have added those dependencies but still no luck. So all this changes , i have done them in my Jax-RS project. The flow is that i add this as an artifact to a an other project that is a car Application project with which i generate the car file that i deploy. Should i add those dependencies or the Import-Package to the pom file of the car Application project or it is fine at the Jax-RS project?